# Youtube API: Default comments settings not applying to videos published via API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using youtube v3 API to publish videos on my channel. I want to moderate all comments made on my videos so I've selected the following in my channel setting. Note that I've chosen for all comments to be held for review by default.
[image: Channel settings]
Now I proceed to publish a video via API. But, it was observed that my video settings were set to *Allow all comments* instead of *Hold all comments for review* as is evident from the below image.
[image: Video setting]
I've gone through the video insert API and did not find any parameter that would configure comment settings for each video. I'm failing to understand why the channel default setting is not selected for videos published via API. Is there any way through which I can change the video comment setting via API?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify comment options via the Data v3 API. This has been a long standing feature request. See the [IssueTracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175046).